# Is it possible to get a list of all reports who are using a certain field as filter?

Tags: reporting

I am doing some work on LeadSource field.

Is there a way to get a list of all the reports who use this field in their filter criteria?

As I am changing the values, the reports that use the field, will not return the correct data, and they need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download all public reports & report types to Force.com IDE and run a text search there (Ctrl+H; or use Mig. Tool if you prefer it). But user's private reports are unavailable that way so there will be still chance that they'll have to manually modify the report definitions.

Watch out for the limit of 5,000 objects fetched in one go. If your organisation has lots of reports (you can run `SELECT COUNT() FROM Report`) you might have to fetch them folder by folder (`SELECT COUNT(Id), OwnerId FROM Report GROUP BY ROLLUP(OwnerId)`).

There's also an interesting functionality to opt-in with Summer'13, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446743/313628 but looks like it'll still mean looping through all reports... I'd just fetch them all and run search locally.

Once downloaded - search for `<column>Lead.LeadSource</column>` and `<column>LeadSource</column>`.

---

Fetching of whole project to the IDE means you can double check if anything still has to be updated:

- formulas, validation rules, workflow rules
- listview definitions, default & available values per record type
- criteria-based sharing rules
- (downloadable in Summer'13) approval processes
- Apex code